# Android Recyclerview with dynamic number of items in row

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, android-recyclerview, adapter

i need to create recycler view adapter for x items placed in rows. Number of items in row should be configurable by some constant in code.
Every item contains title static background picture and two other images placed over background based on data from item object.
Please help me how to achieve this look

[Here is scratch how row should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wlj8.png)

EDIT: if constant for row is for example 4 and i have 11 items, i need to generate also multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a horizontal recyclerview.

//EDIT

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    int spacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.zero);
    playBinding3.recycler.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacing));

    HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(list, this);
    recycler.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
```

Where recycler is your recyclerview and Recyclerview adapter. Use the recyclerview with cardviews and you should be able to easily achieve that look.
'list' is your list of items to show.

I guess you are looking for a recycleview with GridLayout where each row of items has multiple columns. Is that it?

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 4);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    int spacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.onespacing);
    recycler.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacing));
```

Where 4 is the number of columns per row. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: so it will be horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview ?

Comment: @Coldnight I have updated my answer. Feel free to ask if I didn't answer it fully or misunderstood you.