# How to show dynamic items in one row of RecyclerView? When the row clicked shows all items again

Tags: java, android

I know how to add items to RecyclerView and show them, but let's say I add some dynamic items to the RecyclerView like this image

[image]

Here After click save button, it creates three rows in the RecyclerView like below image, which I don't want it creates three rows.

[image]

Instead I want to create one row, and when I clicked in that row then shows the three items like this image.

[image]

AddChecklist class

```
public class AddChecklist extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAddItem;
public LinearLayout linearLayout;
DbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_checklist);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addView();
        }
    });
}

public  void addView(){

    View checklistView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist_view, null, false);
    EditText etChecklistItem = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
    CheckBox checkBox = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

    linearLayout.addView(checklistView);

    ImageView imgDelete = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);

    imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeView(checklistView);
        }
    });
}

public void removeView(View view){
    linearLayout.removeView(view);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btn_save:
            ChecklistHelper checklistHelper = new ChecklistHelper();
            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                EditText etChecklistItem = v.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
                CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    checklistHelper.setStatus("1");
                }
                else
                    checklistHelper.setStatus("0");
                dbHelper.insertChecklist(checklistHelper.getStatus(), etChecklistItem.getText().toString(), DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class ChecklistItems extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

String content;
String status;
boolean isEditChecklist = false;
private ChecklistAdapter checklistAdapter;
DbHelper dbHelper;
List<ChecklistHelper> checks;
int id;
ChecklistHelper checklistHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_items);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
    checklistHelper = new ChecklistHelper();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    checks = dbHelper.getChecklists();
    checklistAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(checks);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(checklistAdapter);
    
}

public class ChecklistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private boolean isEnableDelete = false;
    List<ChecklistHelper> checkList;

    public ChecklistAdapter(List<ChecklistHelper> checkList) {
        this.checkList = checkList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.checklist_layout_child, parent, false);
        return new ChecklistChildViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ChecklistChildViewHolder checklistChildViewHolder = (ChecklistChildViewHolder) holder;
        checklistChildViewHolder.updateVisibility(isEnableDelete);
        checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(checkList.get(position).getContent());

        checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                String txt = checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.getText().toString();
                if (b)
                    checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(lineThrough(txt));
                else
                    checklistChildViewHolder.checkBox.setText(txt);
            }
        });

        checklistChildViewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dbHelper.deleteChecklist(id);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkList.size();
    }

    public void updateItems(boolean isEnableDelete){
        this.isEnableDelete = isEnableDelete;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ChecklistChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView delete, edit;


        ChecklistChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_child);
            edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_child);
            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        public void updateVisibility(boolean isEnableDelete){

            if (isEnableDelete) {
                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    //     long id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        
        case R.id.edit:
            
            isEditChecklist = true;
            checklistAdapter.updateItems(true);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            break;

        case R.id.save:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checklistAdapter.updateItems(false);
            isEditChecklist = false;
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.delete:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete Checklist");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dbHelper.deleteChecklist(id);

                    //  checklistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checklist deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share relevant code with the question

Comment: Do you have some code to show? It is hard to understand the problem just by looking at random images.

Comment: @AskNilesh shared the code

Comment: @gioravered look shared the code

Comment: Please refer the below ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810890/android-recyclerview-with-dynamic-number-of-items-in-row

Comment: @Omer123 I'm not able to understand what is exact requirement here

Comment: @AskNilesh I want to add dynamic number of checklists to RecyclerView. let's say I add 9 items to the RecyclerView first row and when I clicked on first row I need to show me all 9 items, this time I add for example 5  checklist items to the second row of the RecyclerView and when I clicked the second row shows 5 items.

Comment: @Deepak read my last comment.. The link you provided is not what I want...

Comment: @Omer123 I think you might be looking for "Expandable ReyclerView". Something like this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view ?

Comment: @gioravered Thanks for for your reply.  I want something like this but when I clicked  (section 0 ) for example, I want to go to another activity and show ( 0, 1،2 ) there.

Comment: @Omer123 I think this is too much to ask for in a single StackOverflow question. You should read a bit about share data between Activities/Fragments and make an attempt to solve it and request help if needed..

Comment: Yea , to be honest, it was a lot to ask, after many tries I fixed the problem, which needed a lot of editting and then updating....